# Is there a word for people who have shared the same locality?

Tags: neologisms, diction

A "contemporary" is someone who has lived at the same time (more-or-less, anyway) as another person. e.g., Bret Harte (1836-1902) can be said to have been a contemporary of Mark Twain (1835-1910).

What about people who have lived in the same place, but at different times (such as myself and Mark Twain (Angels Camp, California)) - is there a word for that? "Congeorary" or so?

Or people who have lived in the same place *and* time (I don't even want to guess at what the word might be)?

Comment: Fellow countryman.

Comment: "lived in the same place and time" - if the place is small enough you could say they were neighbours

Comment: I don't suppose you'd take [homeboy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homeboy)

Comment: @Josh61: Two people who lived in Angels Camp would be fellow villagemen, maybe (townsmen? citymen?)

Comment: Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fellow+townsman%2Cfellow+countryman+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfellow%20townsman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfellow%20countryman%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

For people who have lived in the same place

As a general term you could use:

> fellow **place_name** resident

Coming from the same country:

> [countryman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/countryman), [compatriot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/inter?dest=/dictionary/compatriot) or [landsman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landsman)

Coming from the same city:

> fellow citizen

Comment: I don't actually live *in* London - but if I did, I certainly wouldn't expect *my fellow citizens* to significantly imply *fellow **Londoners*** as opposed to people who live elsewhere within the country.